# OpenGL ES 1.x Shaders

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, shader

I am trying to find examples of how to implement a simple shader for OpenGL ES 1.x (specifically for the iPhone).  I have never worked with shaders before, but I do understand what they are used for.  I think that once I am able to load a simple shader in the simulator I will be able to take it from there and do what I need to do.
Thanks for the help,
~Eric

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The iPhone currently uses [OpenGL ES 1.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES) which doesn't support a programmable pipeline. OpenGL ES 2.0 does seem to have them though and also be **not** compatible with 1.1 .

Answer (score 2):

From [this post](http://diaryofagraphicsprogrammer.blogspot.com/2008/12/ip-programming-tip-5.html):

> The pixel shader of the iP* platform is programmed via texture combiners.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the hardware shaders on the iPhone are already being used by the OS for its features in CoreAnimation and OpenGL ES.  This means they are not available to you.

Are you looking for a software shader?  Try http://unity3d.com/unity/features/shaders

Comment: OpenGL ES 1.1 doesn't support shaders at all as it's specifically designed for a fixed function pipeline.

Comment: You're correct that shader functionality isn't exposed by OpenGL on the iPhone, however I don't think there's anything to suggest that the OS is using shaders. Do you have any citation regarding that?

Comment: I do not have a citation, just other peoples guesses