# Create lightning in OpenGL ES 1.1

Tags: iphone, animation, opengl-es

I need to create good looking lightning using OpenGL ES 1.1 (iPhone) and was planning on using shaders.  However, when I asked about it in a previous question ([OpenGL ES 1.x Shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543948/opengl-es-1-x-shaders)) I was informed there that this was probably not an option on the iPhone.

So now I am back at square one, wondering how I might make a lightning animation.  It does not need to look ultra-realistic.  I have already tried to use things like triangles stripped together.  While this method does work, it is not as good as I had hoped it would look.

Does anyone have any ideas on the subject?

Thanks again,
~Eric

Comment: Some people have pointed out that the question is a little ambiguous.  I am trying to create a lightning bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is to compute the path of the lightning bolt using a Perlin function, rendering it to a glow buffer, creating a nice looking blur using a Gaussian blur shader and then merge it with your scene.

Answer (score 4):

Try using a triangle strip textured with a gradient from black to a low-saturation blue or purple, to white. Set your blending to additive (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE).

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe adapt the code from [this project](http://www.nitrogen.za.org/projectinfo.asp?id=14). Although it's not ObjC/C, it does use OpenGL.

[Here](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1512.asp) is an article that describes the effect in more detail and provides a VB/DirectX implementation.

Comment: I looked at these examples and have achieved a better effect than the first one.  The second looks promising from the screen shot, but when I execute their code it comes out very bad.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but what's wrong with simply using `glLight()` and the fixed functionality like everybody else?

Comment: Lighting is generally associated as much was the streak across the screen as the brightning of things.

Comment: Oh, I misread lightning for Lighting. It's still however unclear what effect you're after and why you think it can't be reproduced by normal means. maybe a visual explanation is due?

Answer (score 0):

Would have to be a very bright light to make it look like lightning and wouldn't you need to shine the light on or through something?