# Using alpha from texture to draw solid color

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

How can I use OpenGLES 1.1 (iPhone) to draw a texture, but only using the alpha to draw some color?

The result should be the exact same alpha mask from the original texture, with a single solid color inside instead of the original colors.

I am using `glDrawArrays` with `glCoordPointer` and `glVertexPointer`.

I think doing two passes, one with the texture and one with a solid color to to this. I just can't seem to find the invert of `glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`.

Edit: after some more looking around, I thinks this should be possible to achieve using `glTexEnvf`. It's just a matter of finding the right arguments.

Comment: I wish that was python related, I'd have a gazillion answers by now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentionned, glTexEnv is the way to go.

To replace the RGB components of your texture and keep its alpha untouched, you could try something like this (this code uses red as replacement color):

```
glColor4f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );

glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE_0 );
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, spriteTexture);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB, GL_REPLACE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_RGB, GL_PREVIOUS);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC1_RGB, GL_TEXTURE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_RGB, GL_SRC_COLOR);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND1_RGB, GL_SRC_COLOR);

// ... draw as usual
```

Here come some explanations.

When using GL_COMBINE, you have complete control on how the input/output of the different texture stages are combined together. In this case, we specify that we want to replace (GL_REPLACE) the RGB components of texture stage 0 with what comes from the previous stage (GL_PREVIOUS) which in this case is a single color (set with glColor4f).

We did not set anything special for the alpha component as we want the regular behavior.
Adding the following lines would have had the same effect as if not included (default behavior):

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA, GL_MODULATE);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC0_ALPHA, GL_PREVIOUS);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SRC1_ALPHA, GL_TEXTURE);   
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND1_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Comment: Thanks for this really informative answer! I had to change `GL_TEXTURE_0` to `GL_TEXTURE0` to make it compile, and add `glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);` after the drawing to make the rest of the rendering work. Now the shape is properly drawn, but always using white as a color. Might it be related to the changes I made?

Comment: I don't think your changes are the reason of your problem and yes, you have to add glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE); after the drawing to return to the default texturing mode. I don't have a clear idea about why you would get white results... Have you properly added the glColor4f() as described in the example?

Comment: Yes, glColor4f is called at the exact same position as in your code example.

Comment: Hummm... You might wanna check that texture unit 1 is properly disabled by calling glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE1 ); glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D ); Check also your that blending is enabled and that blending function is set like this: glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Comment: I've posted a code snippet that you can use to update the GLSprite sample that come with XCode and that will do what you want. All you have to do is edit EAGLView.m to set the blend function properly in setupView and replace drawView with the one provided at http://snipt.org/pPko/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Take yer bounty!

Comment: Thank you! Let us know if you find the reason why you got white results... I'm really curious.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use OpenGL ES 2.0, you could do this with a custom fragment shader. If you're using a framework that is built on 1.1 or are targeting devices that don't support 2.0, this won't be much help. But if you can, this is how you do it:

```
uniform lowp sampler2D sampler; // which texture unit to use
uniform lowp vec4 solidColor;

varying highp vec2 fragmentTexCoord;

void main()
{
    // Get the color with an alpha of zero
    vec4 color = vec4(1,1,1,0) * solidColor;
    // Get the alpha from the texture, zero the r,g,b components
    vec4 alpha = vec4(0,0,0,1) * texture2D(sampler, fragmentTexCoord);
    // their sum is the solid color with the alpha mask of the texture
    gl_FragColor = color + alpha;
}
```

If you can ensure the solidColor has an alpha of zero you could skip the multiplication step.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not too sure if I can use shaders. Isn't there a way to use the inverse of glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); to do this?

Comment: This answer says that OpenGLES 1.1 doesn't support custom shaders : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543948/opengl-es-1-x-shaders/544022#544022.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the answer, even if it's not useful to you, might be worth preserving for someone else doing a search.

Answer (score 0):

`glBlendFunc(source_factor, dest_factor)` translates to:

```
dest= source*source_factor + dest*dest_factor
```

So `glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` is:

```
dest= source*0 + dest*(1 - source.alpha)
```

The second pass (which isn't the inverse) should be `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE)`:

```
dest= source*source.alpha + dest
```

since you already applied the alpha mask in the first pass. Although you still need to figure out how to apply a constant color with alpha instead of the source texture.